# Get version from directory name

Tags: maven

I have bunch of projects. All of them must have the same version = branch directory name("7.15.0" for example).

To achieve that, i make one parent pom with code:

```
<version>${branch}</version>
<properties>
    <branch>${project.file.parentFile.parentFile.parentFile.name}</branch>
</properties>
```

Most of my projects and subprojects are in directories, where ../.. is branch directory. Their poms contains this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>parentPomGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentPomArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>${branch}</version>
</parent>
```

But not all projects is on the same level, so i must control and check where they is, and if needed add to their pom correct branch path:

```
<properties>
    <branch>${project.file.parentFile.parentFile.name}</branch>
</properties>
```

also when project builds, in the log i see :

```
[INFO] Building appcore-utils ${project.file.parentFile.parentFile.name}
```

If i set constant in branch - log contains version. Tell me please, how can i resolve property "branch" only once in my parent pom? So if i use ${branch} in child project, it resolves to constant, which already calculated in parent pom. Or maybe there is another way to use branch directory name in version of projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the goal you're trying to achieve is valid in terms of the current (3.1+) maven. The `version` tag now should be filled with a constant despite the fact that a while ago it could be possible to use an expression there as described in [Maven version with a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123013/maven-version-with-a-property) , look at the last comment by @JanPeta. BTW the solution by Frederic Close doesn't work anymore (for maven-3.1.1 installed in my system).

Alternatively you can change the version of the *artifacts* generated in your project, and I have a working solution for that (instead of taking version from a directory name, I use `git describe...` output) but it's really, really ugly and now I think it's not worth the time I spent fixing all the issues with this approach.

Comment: Thank for your answer! I use now mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3.