# Maven: How to reference the build directory of a child project in a parent POM?

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module Maven project where some modules have to be built as a Docker image. I tried to put all of the configuration in the parent POM like so:

Parent POM:

```xml
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <baseImage>java</baseImage>
          <imageName>${project.artifactId}</imageName>
          <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <targetPath>/</targetPath>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-executable</directory>
              <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
              <include>lib/*.jar</include>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Child POM:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
      <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

But when I run `mvn docker:build` on the child project I get an error because the `project.build.directory` property was resolved to the target directory of the parent POM, instead of the child's target directory.

Is it possible to delay the expansion of the properties in the parent POM? Or to reference the `project.*` properties of the child from the parent POM?

Comment: Not possible , if you do mvn docker:build in child ,  ${project.build.directory} =  child/target , beacause your plugin is in pluginManagement. Show log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I also used properties for the version (like this: [Maven version with a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123013/maven-version-with-a-property)). That only works (kind of) when running Maven from the aggregator POM.
Switching to explicit versions (and using maven-release-plugin to update them) solved this problem.