# How to reference a file in a folder in the parent pom project

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I am trying to reference a file in a folder in a parent pom project from inside the parent pom file. The plugin is as follows

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>assemble</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                <ignoreDirFormatExtensions>true</ignoreDirFormatExtensions>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>\win-assemble\fitech-java-service-windows-package.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

The package directory looks as follows
[image: Structure of parent pom]

If i hard code the path to the file on the filesystem then my parent projects build correctly. Without using a hardcoded path i cannot reference this file at all. Does anyone know how to solve this please?

Thanks

Comment: haven't you check -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669964/maven-how-to-reference-the-build-directory-of-a-child-project-in-a-parent-pom?rq=1

Comment: Maven – Parent and Child POM Example - https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/

Comment: i cant see any relevance to those links you just posted

Comment: Have you got an answer from their sites

Comment: No because it is not possible - its pacakaged as a pom. I made a new depedency packaged as a jar with my files in resouces and included that in my parent pom