# Maven - command line to updates dependency by groupId

Tags: maven

I would like to update dependencies just "groupA". How can I do this?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupA</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>groupA</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>groupB</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: first you can set a property to store the group A version. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123013/maven-version-with-a-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
mvn versions:use-latest-versions -Dincludes=groupA:*:*:*:*
```

?

This should update all Dependencies that are of the desired groupId.