# Java OSGi implementation for the project

Tags: java, frameworks, osgi

A company has given me a task and I need to learn OSGi for this task and run the project with OSGi services.I dont have any experience with OSGi. And I could not find a proper resource on the internet where I can learn OSGi.Every source says different containers or different things to start with so i couldnt gather all of those informations together.
If i want to explain my project i have a calculator that converts words to numbers and does mathematical operations.And i need 2 services, one for the matematical operations and other one is for the ui. Are there anyone can help me about this project?

i tried to use apache karaf and eclipse equinox but couldnt be able to use both of them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776222/how-to-start-with-osgi